# how to set value limit to zero?

Tags: java, oop, user-interface

It's my first time doing this in a program and I was wondering if there is a way to set the limit to zero. The max value is 100 and when the user used it all up, the min value should be 0 and shouldn't be less than 0. This is the code that I came up with. Thanks for any input, help and ideas.

```
 private class SliderListener implements ChangeListener {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent sl) {
            int iSlider, dSlider, sSlider, wSlider;

            iSlider = intSlider.getValue();
            dSlider = dexSlider.getValue();
            sSlider = strSlider.getValue();
            wSlider = wisSlider.getValue();

            //Store the points in the display field
            points.setText(Double.toString(100 - ( iSlider + dSlider
                + sSlider + wSlider )));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you referring to the min value of Double.toString(100 - ( iSlider + dSlider + sSlider + wSlider )) ?

Comment: `Math.max(0, otherNum)`

Comment: Yes. When I slide the first three to 25 each, on the fourth one it should never go over 25. @maheeka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put it simply:

```
int sliderSum = iSlider + dSlider + sSlider + wSlider;
int master = Math.max (0, 100-sliderSum);
points.setText ( Double.toString (master) );
```

Side note: if your sliders can sum to over 100, then you'll need to think about what's supposed to happen in that case. Should the sliders be allocated some portion of the 100? Should they be forbidden from being set so high that they sum over 100? Or maybe this isn't important, in which case you're fine?

Comment: Thank you! That helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is, basically create an if statement to prevent it from being over 100 like this,

```
if(iSlider + dSlider + sSlider + wSlider > 100) {
    //do something that changes it
}
```

Or better yet make a method that changes their values that will also do checks like the one I showed you to prevent them going over.